# Changing visibility property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which has a class name myClass and id name myId. The div has following style.

```
.myClass {
    height: 74%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

When i try to change visibility from hidden to visible doing this

```
$('#myId').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
```

I am using id in JQuery instead of class because same class is applied to others elements too. My div is still not visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rj71cvLe/

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with that. Try providing a complete, reduced test case.

Comment: Your code is correct and it works fine, you should provide more information to let us understand the root of this problem. http://codepen.io/toroncino/pen/nughx

Comment: I am creating a dynamic div and setting is visibility to hidden. After some action i am setting its visibility to visible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by the following ways

```
$('#myId').css('display','block');

$('#myId').css('display','inline');

$('#myId').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try :

```
$('#myId').css('display', 'block');
```

or Try:

```
<style>
.visible { display:block !important;}
</style>
$('#myId').addClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `visibility: hidden;` to `display: none;`

then update jQuery

```
$('#myId').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

in css the  visibility property  effects to content inside the tag while display property effects to total tag, that means if you apply `display:none;` it will remove entire tag but `visibility:hidden` hide the content inside that tag.

Since :visible is a jQuery selector you can use opacity instead of visibility to hide the content inside the tag.

```
$('#myId').css('opacity','1');
$('#myId').css('opacity','0');
```

if you need to hide the entire tag, better go with display none

Answer (score 0):

just go simple, there is an api available in jquery for hiding and showing up DOM elements. Try as follows

```
   $('#myId').hide(); // for hiding the element

    $('#myId').show(); // to show up the element
```